# Use of "is"/"are"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

What is correct to say in the following case? :

My shoes *are* something I need for..

Or

My shoes *is* something I need for..

Is one of these sentences wrong grammatically or are they both correct, and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question on ELU: [Agreement in “(Singular Noun) Is/Are (Plural Noun)”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English you always use/say *are* after a plural subject.

In this case the subject is *my shoes* and it can be replaced by *they* instead of *it*. So with a plural subject, *are* conjugation is used.

---

See [ECEnglish.com: Is or Are?](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/is-or-was)

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to use "My shoes **are**" because "shoes" is plural.

Answer (score 1):

A linking verb (are) always follows up with its *subject*. Whenever there is a decision to make whether to use is or are,  always look at the noun. If the noun is singular or plural or there is more than one noun.
Eg:

Joe's favorite dessert *is* blueberry muffins.

Blueberry muffins *are* Joe's favorite dessert.

Similarly, if the subject is *My shoes* (which is plural),  the correct usage will be :
My shoes *are* something I need for..

If the subject is a pair of shoes which is singular. In this case, the correct usage will be :
A pair of shoes *is* something I need for..

[Subject-Verb Agreement](http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/SubjectVerb.html#linking)