# What shoes are/is she wearing

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

For some reason, it sounds a bit off to me. I know that shoes are plural, but they come with a pair, which singular.

What shoes *are* she wearing?

OR

What shoes *is* she wearing?

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/129416/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subject is "she". So the verb should agree with "she"

> she **is** wearing or
>
> is she wearing? (interrogative)

"Shoes" is an object here. The verb doesn't agree with it.

Comment: Moreover, _What uniform are **they** wearing?_ (When we change the *she* to *they*, we change the verb from *is* to *are*.)

Comment: @J.R. It sounds like *one uniform for all of them*. I prefer, "**What uniform is each of them wearing?**"

Comment: @SovereignSun - No, you're missing the point. Imagine a sports team that wears [three uniforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_jersey). We are on our way to the game. I may ask, "What uniform are they wearing?" because all players will wear the same (colored) uniform.  I would certainly **not** ask, "What uniform is each of them wearing?" because that makes it sounds like half the team might be wearing, say, the green uniform, and the other half white.

Comment: @J.R. Oh, yeh, that "**uniform**". Surely then you're right. It's an uncountable noun in this case.